# Why a .NET Core 6 console app can't start another console app from within itself (Process.Start()) in WSL while debugging in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A .NET Core 6 console app can't start another console app from within itself (using Process.Start()) in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) while debugging in Visual Studio.

Here is the minimal setup to reproduce.
There is first .NET Core console application:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(".", "ConsoleApp2");
            using (process)
            {
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And the second console app can be almost anything, say, the simplest Main(string[] args) method with "Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");"

When debugging this code in WSL in Visual Studio 2022 I keep getting the exception below:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=An error occurred trying to start process './ConsoleApp2' with working directory '/mnt/c/Temp/TestProject2/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0'. No such file or directory
  Source=System.Diagnostics.Process
  StackTrace: (is skiped for brevity)
```

Have tried to use different paths to pass-in. When use this one:

```
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(path, "ConsoleApp2.dll");
```

I get an exception below:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I'm pretty much stuck **what to try to get the second console app running.
Can anyone help?**

*Please note*, that I know that "console app starting another one" can be substituted with, for example app using library, but at this stage there are project's requirements why we must stick with this approach.

*Please also note*, a fun observation:
if you a path like this one below (note 'exe' in the console app name):....

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Process process = new Process();
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(path, "ConsoleApp2.exe");
            using (process)
            {
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

...from the second console (which code is below):....

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The second console!");

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
                Console.WriteLine("The second console: I'm on Windows:\r\n");
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
                Console.WriteLine("The second console: I'm on Linux:\r\n");
        }
```

...you get the output (below)  (you get the second console running though :) ):

```
Hello, World!
The second console!
The second console: I'm on Windows:
```

So again, **can anyone help to get one console app starting another one so the it can be debugged in WSL from Visual Studio?**